# Arithmetic conflicts vs conflicts in Z3 solver statistics

Tags: z3

I am studying two QF_LIA satisfiability based task scheduling problems using Z3.

### Questions

1. What is the difference between arith-conflicts and conflicts in the statistics reported by Z3?
2. Is one of these metrics a good way of quantifying how easy/hard it was for Z3 to solve the problem? I find that solve time for the first case is lower than the second, I am trying to support this/explain this using some solver statistics measured by Z3.
3. Problem 1 has more clauses than problem 2 (61k vs 10k). But I see a huge difference in arith-add-rows (1M vs 7M). What does this field mean?

### Statistics for Problem 1

Solve time: 5s

Z3 Stats:

> (:arith-add-rows      1274977
>    :arith-assert-lower  631097
>    :arith-assert-upper  1736529
>    :arith-bound-prop    84528
>    :arith-conflicts     938
>    :arith-pivots        11305
>    :binary-propagations 2934957
>    :conflicts           10288
>    :decisions           30244
>    :del-clause          14335
>    :eliminated-vars     54
>    :final-checks        1
>    :max-memory          26.31
>    :memory              11.47
>    :minimized-lits      52633
>    :mk-bool-var         9577
>    :mk-clause           61136
>    :num-allocs          62610792
>    :propagations        5336053
>    :restarts            9
>    :rlimit-count        60060905)

### Statistics for Problem 2

Solve time: 12s

Z3 Stats:

> (:arith-add-rows      7360423
>    :arith-assert-lower  98284
>    :arith-assert-upper  106749
>    :arith-bound-prop    7940
>    :arith-conflicts     3859
>    :arith-pivots        24323
>    :binary-propagations 77194
>    :conflicts           4190
>    :decisions           13619
>    :del-clause          1012
>    :eliminated-vars     64
>    :max-memory          21.89
>    :memory              4.69
>    :minimized-lits      14385
>    :mk-bool-var         3329
>    :mk-clause           10681
>    :num-allocs          33767877
>    :propagations        236651
>    :restarts            7
>    :rlimit-count        608859507)

Answer (score 2):

1. My understanding is that *conflicts* counts the number of literal assignments that Z3 tried but that later on turned out to yield a conflict. My guess thus is that *arith-conflicts* counts the number of conflicts the arithmetic subsolver(s) caused.
2. A high number of conflicts could indicate that Z3 didn't proceed very goal-directed, i.e. that it explored parts of the solution candidate space without actually finding a solution. That's my interpretation of conflicts, though; not sure of the Z3 team would agree.
3. No idea what *arith-add-rows* means. You could grep Z3's sources to see where it is incremented.